# limit access of non super-user role in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, permissions, roles

I have two roles in postgres one is **postgres** which is **super admin** and another is **developers** which is only **create db** access ONLY.

```
 Role name  |                         Attributes                         | Member of
------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 developers | Create DB                                                  | {}
 postgres   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

I created database under **developers** but when I access the developers role I still can see other databases that is not under me.

Steps to reproduce:

1) **login as developers**

```
psql -U developers -d sampledb
```

2) **check all databases using \l**

```
       Name          |   Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |    Access privileges
---------------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------
 another_db          | postgres   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres           +
                     |            |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 developers          | postgres   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres           +
                     |            |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres  +
                     |            |          |             |             | developers=CTc/postgres
 sampledb            | developers | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 postgres            | postgres   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 template0           | postgres   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres            +
                     |            |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1           | postgres   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres            +
                     |            |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

I should not be able to access other databases that is not under **developers** role like `another_db` which is owned by `postgres`

I tried to revoke access

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE another_db FROM developers;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE another_db FROM developers;
```

but I can still connect the developers role to another_db database

```
sampledb=> \c another_db
You are now connected to database "another_db" as user "developers".
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CONNECT` has never been granted to that user, so revoking it has no effect.

You'll have to revoke the privilege `FROM PUBLIC` and grant it to the roles that should have it.

There is no supported way to limit access to database metadata like the list of databases in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I also have an issue where I logged in as developers but when I list all databases I can see the another_db which is not owned by me. It should not be visible because developers is not the owner.

Comment: That is not negotiable in PostgreSQL. Everybody can see metadata, that is not considered a security problem in PostgreSQL.